# Exception handling for one class

Tags: java, spring

Is there a way to handle exceptions for one specific class in a method?

I don't know maybe using Spring in the application-context.xml

Something like this:

```
public class SubsystemFacade {

  public String method1() throws CustomException {
   //do something
  }

  public String method2() throws CustomException {
   //do something
  }

  private String exceptionHandlerForThisClass(CustomException e) {
   //do something with the exception
  }

}
```

Instead of use multiple try catch blocks in all methods.

Answer (score 0):

That's what the [@ExceptionHandler](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/ExceptionHandler.html) annotation is for.

```
@ExceptionHandler(SomeException.class)
public void handleSomeException(SomeException e) {
    // Log the exception or whatever
}
```

It will be called if an exception occurs in the same class, which needs to be a Spring component.

Comment: Can I define it in my application-context.xml like a bean?

Comment: You'll have to check the documentation for the version you're using. I haven't touched the XML config for years.

Comment: I tested it yesterday but didn't works. I will try again today.

Comment: If the documentation for your version says that it works, it works. If not, then it won't work.

Comment: Yes, sure about that. I was saying that I tried with ExceptionHandler annotation but didn't work. I'm doing something wrong sure for that.

Comment: Make sure that you read the requirements in the Javadoc. Mainly about the return types for the handler method. The handlers are quite flexible though.